# iCal calendar for official holidays in Berlin city

Tags: calendar, ical

Where I can get an iCal calendar for official holidays in Berlin city? Any thing like that?

Answer (score 1):

schulferien.org lists all german regional publich and school holidays in multiple format in your case, try the following:

> http://www.schulferien.org/iCal/Ferien/icals/Ferien_Berlin_2014.ics

Answer (score 0):

Like this one?: [German Holiday Calendar](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/calendars/germanholidaycalendar.html)

I googled: `http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/calendars/ Germany holiday`

Comment: I can Google also. The problem is that the holidays aren't the same across Germany. Each state has its own calendar in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

The update url for Ferien und Feiertage Deutschland is:
http://www.schulferien.org/deutschland/ical/

They seem to be update every year!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.